# oci_connect() only works on cli

Tags: php, database, oracle, command-line-interface, pecl

Ive installed httpd and httpd-devel packages and installed php and php-devel on a server. I downloaded and installed the basic client and sdk for oracle and then proceeded to use PECL to install OCI8 extension.

When I try running the oci_connect function page on CLI, It works fine. But when I try to load the same php page over http, i get the following error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in /var/www/html/index.php on line 10**

I have compared the php ini from both and notice that **/etc/php.d/oci8.ini** file is loaded in the cli and the http version

however, the module details are only available on the cli version:

```
oci8

OCI8 Support => enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support => disabled
OCI8 Version => 2.0.8
Revision => $Id: f04114d4d67cffea4cdc2ed3b7f0229c2caa5016 $
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 12.1.0.2.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version => 12.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
oci8.connection_class => no value => no value
oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
oci8.events => Off => Off
oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off
oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20
```

I cant for the life of me figure out why only one loads the extension properly when they both have the same configuration file.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by disabling SELINUX